# Procps appears to be broken, and I can't figure out how to fix it

Tags: apt

I've managed to develop some problem with procps after running updates on my system. Basically, running apt-get upgrade outputs this:

```
root@crackerjam:~# apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
4 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Setting up mysql-server-5.7 (5.7.12-0ubuntu1.1) ...
Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-5.7 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up procps (2:3.3.10-4ubuntu2) ...
update-rc.d: warning: start and stop actions are no longer supported; falling back to defaults
Job for systemd-sysctl.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status systemd-sysctl.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript procps, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing package procps (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of samba:
 samba depends on procps; however:
  Package procps is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package samba (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
 mysql-server depends on mysql-server-5.7; however:
  Package mysql-server-5.7 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-5.7
 procps
 samba
 mysql-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

All of the dependencies point to procps as the problem. What can I do to fix it?

Comment: Possibly related? https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lxd/+bug/1580984